# How to run the animation thread for a Java Swing game from a launcher?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation, awt-eventqueue

I am a bit new to threading, so bear with me.  All relevant classes will be below the text in one place for easier reference.

**Backstory:**

I created a simple pong-like game following this tutorial: http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game1.html

Everything worked perfectly, then I made modifications to better understand how it all works.  In the tutorial, there is a main method from which the animations are played continuously. According to the tutorial author, `Thread.sleep(10)` "...tells the processor that the thread which is being run must sleep for 10 ms, which allows the processor to execute other threads and in particular the AWT-EventQueue thread which calls the paint method."

Now, my question is this:

(Just for fun and to practice Java,) I have created a "launcher" for all the various small programs and games I make.  I have yet to get the pong game to work inside the launcher. Without a main method inside the pong frame, the animation never runs.  I left the main method in in the code below, so that it works. How would I go about launching the animation from somewhere other than main?

Here's the code:

The Frame and main method:

```
package pongGame;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PongMainGUI extends JFrame
{
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;

    private static AnimationPanel panel;

    public PongMainGUI()
    {
        //This line sets the title, and, since it calls the super constructor, it calls setTitle().
        super("Pong!");

        panel = new AnimationPanel(this);

        //This method simply makes the screen appear in the center of whatever size screen you are using.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        new PongMainGUI();
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("PongMainGUI");
            panel.repaint();
            panel.move();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

The Animation Panel:

```
package pongGame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AnimationPanel extends JPanel
{   
    PongMainGUI frame;
    Ball ballClass;
    Racquet racquetClass;
    boolean bool = false;

    public AnimationPanel(PongMainGUI frame)
    {
        this.frame = frame;
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {

            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) 
            {

            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
            {

            }
        });
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                racquetClass.keyPressed(e);
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                racquetClass.keyReleased(e);
            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
            {

            }
        });

        //This is needed to ensure that the keyboard will register properly and receive focus.
        setFocusable(true);
        ballClass = new Ball(this);
        racquetClass = new Racquet(this);
    }

    public void move()
    {
        //ballClass.moveBall();
        racquetClass.moveRacquet();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        System.out.println("AnimationPanel paint method");
        //This method clears the panel so it appears as if the circle is moving.
        super.paint(g);

        //Better version of Graphics.
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        //This method turns antialiasing on, which cleans up the corners.
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ballClass.paint(g2d);
        racquetClass.paint(g2d);
    }
    public void gameOver()
    {
        System.out.println("Game over method");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.exit(ABORT);
    }

}
```

The Ball "sprite":

```
package pongGame;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Ball 
{
    int xCoordinate = 0;
    int yCoordinate = 0;

    //1 = right movement, -1 = left
    int xDirection = 1;
    int yDirection = 1;
    private final static byte ballWidth = 30;
    private final static byte ballHeight = 30;

    private AnimationPanel panel;

    public Ball(AnimationPanel panel)
    {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        //This creates the actual circle with a specified width and height.
        //Because super.paint(g) is called at the start, a new circle is created each time.
        g2d.fillOval(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, ballWidth, ballHeight);

        System.out.println("Ball paint method");

        moveBall();
    }
        //What this method does is add 1 to the x and y coordinates each time it's called.  However, getWidth() and getHeight() are used to determine the current panel size, not the frame size.
        //Then, whatever the width and/or height is is subtracted so the circle does not completely disappear from view.
        public void moveBall() 
        {
            if (xCoordinate + xDirection < 0)
            {
                xDirection = 1;
            }
            else if (xCoordinate + xDirection > panel.getWidth() - ballWidth)
            {
                xDirection = -1;
            }

            if (yCoordinate + yDirection < 0)
            {
                yDirection = 1;
            }
            else if (yCoordinate + yDirection > panel.getHeight() - ballHeight)
            {
                System.out.println("Ball moveBall method");
                panel.gameOver();
            }

            if (collision() == true)
            {
                yDirection = -1;
                yCoordinate = panel.racquetClass.getPaddleHeight() - ballHeight;
            }
            xCoordinate = xCoordinate + xDirection;
            yCoordinate = yCoordinate + yDirection;
        }
        public Rectangle getBounds() 
        {
            return new Rectangle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, ballWidth, ballHeight);
        }
        private boolean collision() 
        {
            return panel.racquetClass.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
        }

}
```

And finally, the Racquet "sprite":

```
package pongGame;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Racquet 
{
    private AnimationPanel panel;

    private int xCoordinate = 0;

    //0 = no movement, 1 is right, -1 is left.
    private byte direction = 0;

    //All of the following values are in pixels.
    private final static byte PADDLE_OFFSET = 100;
    private final static byte PADDLE_WIDTH = 120;
    private final static byte PADDLE_HEIGHT = 10;

    public Racquet(AnimationPanel panel) 
    {
        this.panel = panel;
    }
    public void moveRacquet() 
    {
        if (xCoordinate + direction > 0 && xCoordinate + direction < panel.getWidth()-60)
            xCoordinate = xCoordinate + direction;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) 
    {
        g.fillRect(xCoordinate, getPaddleHeight(), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        //move();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        direction = 0;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            direction = -1;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            direction = 1;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() 
    {
        return new Rectangle(xCoordinate, getPaddleHeight(), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    }
    public int getPaddleHeight()
    {
        return panel.getHeight() - PADDLE_OFFSET;
    }
}
```

This may or may not help, but this is the code for the launcher I wanted to use to open the game:

This is the "main menu":

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;

import painter.MainPainterGUI;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * This class serves to create the launcher gui for the program.
 * It extends JFrame.
 * @author Jackson Murrell
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LauncherGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    //A couple constants that are used for sizing things.
    private final short WINDOW_HEIGHT = 225;
    private final short WINDOW_WIDTH = 550;
    private final byte BLANK_SPACE = 25;

    //Panels to use for adding in components.
    JPanel textPanel, buttonPanel, mainPanel;

    //Buttons for user input and selection.
    JButton calculator, colorChooser, timer, exit, primeNumberTester, game, painter;

    //A text label that will be used for giving the user
    //instructions on the program.
    JLabel textLabel;

    //A constructor to create the GUI components when an object of this class is created.
    public LauncherGUI()
    {
        //This call's the parent method's (JFrame) setTitle method.
        super("Omni-program");

        //These methods set various options for the JFrame.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        textPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        calculator = new JButton("Calculator");
        colorChooser = new JButton("Color Chooser");
        timer = new JButton("Timer");
        primeNumberTester = new JButton("Prime Number Tester");
        game = new JButton("Games");
        exit = new JButton("Exit Launcher and Programs");
        painter = new JButton("Painter");

        calculator.addActionListener(this);
        colorChooser.addActionListener(this);
        timer.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        primeNumberTester.addActionListener(this);
        game.addActionListener(this);
        painter.addActionListener(this);

        textLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to the launcher!  Click the button for the mini-program you would like to run.", 0);

        textPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(BLANK_SPACE));
        textPanel.add(textLabel);

        buttonPanel.add(calculator);
        buttonPanel.add(colorChooser);
        buttonPanel.add(timer);
        buttonPanel.add(primeNumberTester);
        buttonPanel.add(game);
        buttonPanel.add(painter);
        buttonPanel.add(exit);

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        mainPanel.add(textPanel);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        //mainPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(BLANK_SPACE));

        add(mainPanel);

        //pack();

        //Having this line at the end instead of the top ensures that once everything is added it is all set to be visible.
        setVisible(true);
    }
    //This method is required since ActionListener is implemented.
    //It will be used to process user input.
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getSource() == calculator)
        {
            new CalculatorGUI();
            dispose();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == colorChooser)
        {
            new ColorChooserGUI();
            dispose();
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == timer)
        {
            new TimerGUI();
            dispose();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == primeNumberTester)
        {
            new PrimeNumberTesterGUI();
            dispose();
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == exit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == painter)
        {
            new MainPainterGUI();
            dispose();
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == game)
        {
            new GameLauncherGUI();
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the actual game launcher:

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import pongGame.PongMainGUI;

public class GameLauncherGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    //A couple constants that are used for sizing things.
    private final short WINDOW_HEIGHT = 225;
    private final short WINDOW_WIDTH = 550;

    private JButton adventureGame, pong, back;

    private JLabel label;

    private JPanel mainPanel, buttonPanel, textPanel;

    public GameLauncherGUI()
    {
        //This call's the parent method's (JFrame) setTitle method.
        super("Omni-program");

        //These methods set various options for the JFrame.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        adventureGame = new JButton("Adventure Game (Broken)");
        adventureGame.addActionListener(this);

        pong = new JButton("Pong");
        pong.addActionListener(this);

        back = new JButton("Back");
        back.addActionListener(this);

        label = new JLabel("Click the button below for the game you wish to play,\nor click back to go to the previous screen.");

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel = new JPanel();

        textPanel.add(label);

        buttonPanel.add(adventureGame);
        buttonPanel.add(pong);
        buttonPanel.add(back);

        mainPanel.add(textPanel);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        add(mainPanel);

        //Having this line at the end instead of the top ensures that once everything is added it is all set to be visible.
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource() == back)
        {
            new LauncherGUI();
            dispose();
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == pong)
        {
            new PongMainGUI();
            dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future posts :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main`is a static method like others, so you can call it from your launcher:

```
PongMainGUI.main(null); // launch the pong game
```

However, note that, in order to avoid lots of trouble, Swing components must be created from the Event Dispatch Thread, as shown in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html). So you should wrap the content of your main method inside a `Runnable` and launch it with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

However (again), by doing so, your `Thread.sleep(10)` will run on the EDT, blocking the GUI responsiveness again. Fortunately, Swing thought of that problem and created a utility called [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) that runs tasks periodically on the EDT (without blocking it):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
         new PongMainGUI();

         Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               System.out.println("PongMainGUI");
               panel.repaint();
               panel.move();
            }
         });
         timer.start();
      }
   });
}
```

This `main()` method will run safely in standalone, or from your launcher.

Comment: Close but not quite -- that needs to be a **Swing** Timer, not a java.util.Timer. Otherwise you're guaranteeing to call `panel.move() off of the EDT.

Comment: @EricLeibenguth So, since my launcher is started from a main method, it's possible to have another one which runs the animation part?  It wasn't terribly relevant, but I have a separate "Main" class which simply creates an instance of LauncherGUI.  I thought it was a nono to have two mains.

Comment: @EricLeibenguth I just had a chance to test this, and wow, this works fantastically.  I wish I could upvote your answer more, but I cannot.  Thanks a lot, i was getting so frustrated trying to figure this out on my own.  :D

Comment: You can have as many `main` methods as you want. The only thing special about them is that they can (but not necessarily will) work as "entry points" in your program.